# Download a spreadsheet from SFTP

Tags: r, curl, ftp

Im trying to down load a spreadsheet from a secured FTP.

I cant use `getURL` function to download it becasue I get error

> Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
>     embedded nul in string:

Then I tried using `getBinaryURL` but I'm not quite sure what to do with binary code that I get.

```
require(RCurl)
require(dplyr)

FileName <- some.xls
credentials <- yaml::yaml.load_file("./config/credentials.yml")
file1 <- paste("ftp:/",credentials$host,"evb/",FileName,sep="/") %>%    
  getBinaryURL(userpwd = credentials$userpwd)
```

I saw some question here that used `download.file` but that doesn't let me provide credentials to the ftp.

Comment: If there is an object named `some.xls` with a value that is a single length character vector that points to a valid file name, then no problem, but otherwise you need to add some quotes. (Also would have expected the protocol string to be `"ftp://"` but maybe the client and server software are more permissive that I expect.

Comment: So look at the result of `paste("ftp:/",credentials$host,"evb/",FileName,sep="/")` and post it here.

Comment: Sorry I can't post details of that FTP. However I can tell you that its a very simple name it has characters digits underscores.

Comment: Here is a 'changed' url `ftp://server1/ecb/data_20150417.xls`